# How to convert this directory "engine\\..\\..\\NewFolder" to absolute directory ( C++ Window )

Tags: c++, windows

How to convert this directory "c:\~~\engine\..\..\NewFolder" to absolute directory.
I have some directory string containing "\..\".
I don't know how to convert this to real path.

I'm on C++, Windows.

Comment: Start by splitting the string into a vector of strings.  Then walk through that vector to build a new vector by using all the rules you would use when reading this as a human.  For each subdirectory name, you will either add or remove one element from this new vector.  Afterwards, recombine with directory separators.  You should end up with `"..\NewFolder".  If your question is actually about how to build an _absolute path_, then you will first need to obtain the current directory and prepend that to your relative directory.

Comment: Since C++17, you can use [`std::filesystem::canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) perhaps?

Comment: @paddy That's doing it the hard way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function for this called [`PathCanonicalize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcanonicalizew) in the Win32 API which you might find useful.

Example usage:

```
TCHAR outbuf [32767];
PathCanonicalize (outbuf, my_path);
```

`outbuf` is as long as it is to handle [long path names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation), which is a user-definable option in Windows 10 and later.  You can, of course (and probably should) allocate this on the heap, and you should check the return code (the function returns `TRUE` if successful).

---

**Update** (thank you Cody, for making me seek this out):

Turns out there's a better way to do this.  From Windows 8 onwards, you can use [`PathAllocCanonicalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathalloccanonicalize) instead.  This has two advantages:

- you don't need to preallocate the output buffer
- it can handle path names longer than `MAX_PATH`

Here's a snippet showing how to use it:

```
TCHAR *path_out;
HRESULT hr = PathAllocCanonicalize (my_path, PATHCCH_ALLOW_LONG_PATHS, &path_out);
if (hr == S_OK)
{
    // do stuff with path_out
    CoTaskMemFree (path_out);
}
```

Be sure to call [`CoInitializeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) somewhere in your code before calling this function, otherwise it will always fail.

Comment: Are you sure that the `ShLwApi` functions actually support these long paths names? The SDK documentation suggests they're still limited to `MAX_PATH`, but of course you never know if that can be trusted.

Comment: Good question @cody, and I think the answer is that it doesn't.  But there's another API call that does - updated my answer.